# Set a non-default schema in Yii Framework with PostgreSQL

Tags: php, postgresql, yii, database-schema

I'm using Yii Framework with PostgreSQL and I need to create new models in a non-default schema. How can I do that?
I tried the following:

**protected/components/PgSchemaConnection.php**

```
class PgSchemaConnection extends CDbConnection {
  protected function initConnection($pdo)
  {
    parent::initConnection($pdo);
    $stmt=$pdo->prepare("set search_path to master, public");
    $stmt->execute();
  }
}
```

**protected/config/main.php**

```
return array(
    ...
    'db'=>array(
            'connectionString' => 'pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=bsc',
        'username' => 'aUser',
        'password' => 'aPass',
        'charset' => 'utf8',
            'class' => 'PgSchemaConnection'
        ),
    ...
)
```

But when I run in console

```
>> model Foo
Warning: the table 'Foo' does not exist in the database.
   generate models/relatedobjective.php
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/cristhian/php_apps/yii-1.1.14.f0fee9/framework/cli/views/shell/model/fixture.php on line 13
PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/cristhian/php_apps/yii-1.1.14.f0fee9/framework/cli/views/shell/model/fixture.php on line 19
   generate fixtures/relatedobjective.php
   generate unit/relatedobjectiveTest.php

The following model classes are successfully generated:
    relatedobjective

If you have a 'db' database connection, you can test these models now with:
    $model=relatedobjective::model()->find();
    print_r($model);
```

Yii does not find the table Foo in the database (Obiously, I have been created the Foo table)

How can I set another schema? What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3):

just provide the full path to your table - including schema name.

With gii, I set 'tableName' field with 'schemaName.tableName'.

Your model will look like:

```
class MyModel extends CActiveRecord{
    ...
    tableName(){
        return 'schemaName.tableName';
    }
```

This model will perform queries with your default 'db' connection config.

Answer (score 0):

you have to change the database connection of that model,

you can overwrite the `getDbConnection()` of that model to use another connection:

```
public function getDbConnection()
{
    return Yii::app()->dbPostgre;
}
```

and now add this connection below your main database connection in `config/main.php`

```
'dbPostgre' => array(
    'connectionString' => 'pgsql:host=localhost;dbname=bsc',
    'class'=>'CDbConnection',
    'username' => 'aUser',
    'password' => 'aPass',
    'charset' => 'utf8',
        'class' => 'PgSchemaConnection'
    ),
),
```

now your good to go,

but one thing, if you want to use gii to generate model from that database, temporarily change the name of **dbPostgre** to **db**

Comment: Thanks for your answer @tinybyte but I don't see a substantial difference between my code and your code. What am I doing wrong?